# Есть ли способ использовать vue как генератор html шаблонов?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, ssr, server-side-rendering

Я сейчас занимаюсь созданием некого стартового шаблона на webpack для себя и маленькой команды. Моя основная цель это создание HTML шаблона без включения Vue в клиентскую сторону. Я попробовал использовать handlebars но он не идет в сравнение с vue-шаблонами. Для меня наверное самым идеальным решением было бы иметь какой нибудь загрузчик для вебпака, который бы позволял просто превратить .vue файлы в HTML и передать их в HtmlWebpackPlugin без! добавления vue в дистрибутив.

Может такой вопрос уже был, я находил похожие за 2018 год, там рекомендовали использовать Nuxt/Gridsome. Покопавшись на гитхабе репозитория nuxt + гугла я понял что возможности "не включать" vue в дистрибутив там нету.

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык.

Comment: Простите пожалуйста, не заметил что при регистрации меня перекинуло на ру версию стака.

Comment: думаю Вам поможет вот это - https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/api/#renderer-rendertostring . Для этого необходимо (без всяких webpack'ов) написать свой сервер, подключить к нему vue-ssr и при обработке запроса рендерить html, с помощью vue

Comment: https://ssr.vuejs.org/ru/guide/#%D0%BF%D0%BEn%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-n%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4n%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE - а вот, по идее, это именно то, что Вам нужно

Comment: Дмытрык, спасибо большое за отклик!)
Я уже читал эти доки и у меня возникла другая идея.
сделать loader\plugin для webpack'a который будет при запросе .template.vue файла создавать новый экземпляр vue, передавать его в renderer  и возвращать html. 
Осталось только осилить вебпак...